# using if/else with function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have tried to write a simple code to compute the median but I got an error.
This is what I wrote

```
median<-function(x){odd.even<-length(x)%%2 if (odd.even = = 0)(sort(x)[length(x)/2]+sort(x)[1+length(x)/2])/2 else (sort(x)[ceiling(length(x)/2)])}
```

and this is the error I got

> Error: unexpected 'if' in "median<-function(x){odd.even<-length(x)%%2 if"

Thanks

Comment: do you know that you need a semicolon or a newline between statements ? I started to edit your code format as @akrun did, but I'm afraid that your problem is probably due to trying to paste all of these commands on the same line together.  With @akrun's edits (and changing `odd.even = = 0` to `odd.even == 0`), this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (you forgot the brackets {)

```
median<-function(x){

  odd.even<-length(x)%%2 

  if (odd.even == 0){    
    (sort(x)[length(x)/2]+sort(x)[1+length(x)/2])/2 
  } else {
    (sort(x)[ceiling(length(x)/2)])
  }

}
```

As pointed out if you want not to use bracket you can always do this, with a new line on the if statement :

```
median<-function(x){
  odd.even<-length(x)%%2 
  if (odd.even == 0) (sort(x)[length(x)/2]+sort(x)[1+length(x)/2])/2 else (sort(x)[ceiling(length(x)/2)])
}
```

Also a return(x) at the end, might help the reading process, although it is not compulsory.

Comment: brackets help, but wouldn't be necessary as long as the "then" clause is a single statement and was on a separate line ...

Comment: True. It is a good habbit to use the bracket. If one wants to use no bracket. the if still has to start on a new line.   

odd.even<-length(x)%%2 #NEWLINE                               
if (odd.even == 0) (sort(x)[length(x)/2]+sort(x)[1+length(x)/2])/2 else (sort(x)[ceiling(length(x)/2)])

Works

Comment: if you want to be particular, you need to have the else on the same line as the preceding bracket